# Método retorna instância, após definição de propriedade

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, terminologia, método

Existe um nome para a prática ou padrão, para este trecho de código?

Exemplo:

```
<?php

class Pessoa
{
   //...
   public setNome($nome)
   {
       $this->nome = $nome;
       return $this;
   }
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta não dá detalhes, mas acredito que se refira ao fato de retornar o `$this`. Isso é usado para criar o que se chama [*fluent interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (embora nem todos casos seja isso mesmo). Desta forma os métodos podem ser encadeados para realizar diversas operações em sequência com o objeto, já que o resultado de cada método é o próprio objeto recebido que em seguida é usado como mensagem para o próximo método.

Essa operação é chamada de [*method chaining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) (esse termo pode ser usado nesse caso independente de analisar como está sendo usado).

Aparentemente o estilo foi criado pelo Eric Evans e [o termo foi cunhado pelo Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html).

Há muitos adeptos e certamente há vantagens. Mas [há detratores](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/fluent-interfaces-are-evil/) e pode ser facilmente abusado. Eu acho que ela é usada para compensar deficiência da linguagem.

Comment: Nossa perfeito cara. Muito obrigada!