# Diferenças na chamada de métodos

Tags: c#

Por que alguns métodos podem ser chamados consecutivamente, exemplo:

```
string a = "";
a.Replace("a", "b").Replace("b","c");// o replace foi chamado 2x
```

E outros não podem ser chamados do mesmo jeito?

```
ClasseA A = new ClasseA();
string a = A.Metodo();
```

Porque isso acontece e qual a diferença dos 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o método publico `Replace()`, que é definido na classe `string`, retorna um instância de objeto que, por acaso, é do mesmo tipo de `a` - neste caso, `string`.

As chamadas em cadeia resultam do fato de você poder invocar o mesmo método de instâncias - possivelmente diferentes, mas não necessariamente - da mesma classe *imediatamente após o retorno do método*.

Se isso não fosse possível você teria que armazenar o valor retornado, e invocar o método pela nova referência:

```
string a = "";
string b = a.Replace("a", "b");
b.Replace("b","c");
```

Se você identificar os passos individuais da sequência de eventos do seu exemplo, você notará o seguinte:

- O método `string.Replace()` é invocado para a instância `a`;
- O valor retornado é também uma instância de `string`.
- O método `string.Replace()` é invocado agora para o valor retornado no passo anterior;
- O valor retornado é uma string.

Uma outra maneira de visualizar este processo:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        new A()
            .Mesmo().Mesmo().Mesmo().Mesmo();

        System.Console.WriteLine();

        new A()
            .Novo().Novo().Novo().Novo();

        System.Console.WriteLine();

        new A() // Cadeia com chamadas mistas
            .Mesmo().Mesmo().Novo().Mesmo().Mesmo().Novo().Mesmo().Mesmo();
    }
}

public class A { // Declaração de classe

    private int counter = 0; //Contador interno da instância

    public A Mesmo() { // O método Mesmo retorna uma instância de A...
        counter++;
        System.Console.Write($"{counter} ");
        return this; // Neste caso, a mesma instância.
    }

    public A Novo() { // O método Novo retorna uma instância de A...
        counter++;
        System.Console.Write($"{counter} ");
        return new A(); // Neste caso, uma nova instância.
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima você pode perceber que tanto o método `A.Mesmo()` quanto `A.Novo()` retornam instâncias de `A`, permitindo assim chamadas encadeadas - porém `A.Novo()` gera novas instâncias enquanto que `A.Mesmo()` retorna a si mesmo (`return this;`).

O resultado compilado do exemplo acima é o seguinte:

```
1 2 3 4 
1 1 1 1 
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ekJGIw)

Comment: Então a capacidade de fazer o encadeamento dos métodos se dá pelo(s) construtor(es)?

Comment: @Marceloawq quase isso - se dá pela *assinatura* do método chamado (mais especificamente, o tipo retornado pelo método). No momento do retorno você pode utilizar qualquer método disponível para o tipo retornado.

Answer (score 8):

Neste caso específico a diferença é que o `Replace()` é um método normal e o `ClasseA()` é um construtor que retorna um objeto que ele acabou de construir, mas pode chamar ele em cadeia, então a pergunta parte de premissa errada:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        new ClasseA().Metodo();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fQ9LVV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X18z4Z). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ChainnedCall.cs).

Obviamente que este exemplo o objeto não será guardado em variável alguma e no fima deste *statement* ele será perdido e fica disponível para coleta a qualquer momento. Se for colocar uma variável para guardar um objeto este será o que for devolvido por `Metodo()` e não o construtor, ou seja, é o último método executado que produzirá algum valor (no exemplo que eu escrevi `Metodo()` retorna `void` então não pode ser guardado).

Se deseja que o objeto seja guardado em variável tem que fazer como está na pergunta, mas só porque é o seu objeto, não é que não pode ser assim, você tem a escolha. No seu exemplo o último método da primeira linha é o construtor então a variável receberá o objeto construído, e a seguinte linha aplica um método em cima do objeto referenciado pela variável que recebeu o objeto logo antes.

```
variavel = new ClasseA().Metodo();
```

funciona, mas o que será guardado na variável é o valor devolvido pelo método, você pode até fazer que seja o objeto, se for seu desejo, um exemplo artificial seria assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var variavel = new ClasseA().Metodo();
        WriteLine(variavel);
    }
}

public class ClasseA {
    public ClasseA Metodo() => this;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SGBb0P). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bT9wOW). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnThis.cs).

Esta técnica chama-se [*method chaining*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147031/101) e costuma ser usada para criar o que se chama *fluent interface*. O `Replace()` da pergunta não usa esta técnica, ele retorna um objeto que ele precisa, não foi retornado o `this`, muito menos de propósito para poder encadear artificialmente, acredito que isto foi explicado no começo da resposta. Estou colocando esse parágrafo porque as outras respostas adotam isso e não é o que a pergunta está mostrando.

Para entender melhor o que corre no primeiro caso é o seguinte:

```
string a = "";
var tmp = a.Replace("a", "b")
tmp.Replace("b","c");
```

Só que esta variável `tmp` não existe no código porque ela não é necessária. Ao contrário do que muita gente achar variáveis só precisam existir se um valor precisa ser armazenado, nem todos valores precisam, eles podem ser usados de forma direta.

Um exemplo que pode mostrar melhor que esse encadeamento é circunstancial:

```
Math.Pow(2, 3).ToString()
```

Aqui ele usa um número para gerar outro número que será a potência e esse número será usado como `string`. Encadeamento de objetos completamente diferentes.

Qualquer método que retorne um valor pode chamar outro método logo em seguida desde que seja um método que aquele objeto tenha disponível, e todos os objetos possuem métodos já que todos derivam de `Object` e este possui métodos. Um método que retorne `void` não pode ser encadeado.

O método é aplicado em cima de um objeto, não importante como ele é obtido, pode ser por uma variável, o mais comum, uma propriedade que se confundo como se fosse uma variável, pode ser um método que retorna um objeto ou pode ser um literal. Percebo que as pessoas se confundem com isso. Exemplo do literais:

```
10.GetHashCode()
"teste".Replace("s", "x")
new []{1, 2, 3}.IndexOf(2)
(1, 2).ToString()
1..3.ToString()
new StringBuilder("abc").Append("xxx")
```

O primeiro exemplo é [bastante ineficiente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/101), mas o `Replace()` retorna um objeto novo que ele acabou de criar (isso é importante, por isso é ineficiente), então ele pode ser usado para passar para outro método que seja do mesmo tipo. Note que tem um erro nesse código porque apesar de ter criado dois novos objetos `string` com modificações, nenhum deles é armazenado em algum lugar e portanto serão perdidos. E se colocar em uma variável é só o resultado do segundo que será armazenado, provavelmente é o que desejam mas criou um objeto sem necessidade e sem perceber, porque provavelmente não sabe que [`string`s são imutáveis em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16063/101).

Reforçando: a pergunta tem a premissa errada que o segundo casos não pide ser feito encadeado se quiser, e o primeiro caso é um encadeamento simples circunstancial e não o *design pattern* chamado *method chaining*.

Comment: Achei válidos os argumentos, mas apenas na 2ª parte da pergunta, no que diz respeito as diferenças entre os 2. Agora, entre a primeira parte, o Porque, não entendi. Fiz uma modificação que acho que vai ilustrar melhor.

Comment: Mudar a pergunta depois que ela foi feita e respondida é algo complicado, mas na verdade eu nem sei o que essa mudança significa, ou até pode significar que queria saber outra coisa. Ou talvez não mude nada importante e minha resposta continua sendo a mesma, talvez tenha só invalidado parte do texto. Se tem alguma dúvida ainda, favor demonstrar isso, mas parece que seria algo que não estava na pergunta.

Comment: Eu ia até editar a resposta pra falar sobre a edição, mas nem dá, invalidou a própria pergunta porque agora o segundo caso quer fazer algo completamente diferente, o que era premissa errada se transformou em algo sem sentido, se quer fazer isso que está na pergunta então foi sua escolha não uma determinação da linguagem, você escreveu um código que não chama consecutivo porque era o que queria.

Answer (score 4):

Esses métodos que aplicam uma ação ao próprio objeto e retornam o próprio objeto modificado seguem o padrão de projeto chamado *Builder*.

Exemplo:

```
// Podemos ter uma classe Pizza definida da seguinte forma:
public class Pizza {
    private TamanhoPizza tamanho;
    private bool comQueijo;
    private bool comOregano;
    private bool comManjericao;

    public Pizza(TamanhoPizza tamanho) {
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
        this.comQueijo = false;
        this.comOregano = false;
        this.comManjericao = false;
    }

    public Pizza ComQueijo() {
        this.comQueijo = true;
        return this;
    }

    public Pizza ComOregano() {
        this.comOregano = true;
        return this;
    }

    public Pizza ComManjericao() {
        this.comManjericao = true;
        return this;
    }

    public void Comer() {
        Console.WriteLine($"Nhami nhami! Que pizza tamanho ${tamanho} ${comQueijo? "e com queijo" : string.Empty} deliciosa!");
        if (comOregano) {
            Console.WriteLine("E ainda com orégano!");
        }
        if (comManjericao) {
            Console.WriteLine("E ainda com manjericão! Hmmm :)");
        }
    }
}

public enum TamanhoPizza {
    Brotinho,
    Media,
    Grande,
    Big,
    Monster
}
```

Para usar a classe Pizza, poderíamos fazer o seguinte:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Pizza pizza = 
            new Pizza(TamanhoPizza.Grande)
                .ComQueijo()
                .ComManjericao();
        ComerPizza(pizza);
    }

    private static void ComerPizza(Pizza pizza) {
        pizza.Comer();
    }
}
```

Baseado no blog de [Luís Ricardo](http://luizricardo.org/2013/08/construindo-objetos-de-forma-inteligente-builder-pattern-e-fluent-interfaces/).

Isto é feito para enriquecer a construção do objeto e evita um construtor com muitos parâmetros que, sem a devida documentação, poderia deixar o código mais difícil de ler.